# How to define a product in Choco (CSP)

Tags: java, constraints, constraint-programming, choco

I am trying to model a tennis scheduling problem, as I explain in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35757846/modeling-tennis-matchups-with-choco-csp). I was lucky to get an answer with the equations describing the problem which allowed me to implement it in Choco, and it looks like it's working good enough.

So what I am about to explain is about the product of the implementation of the previous post's answer.

Basically I will end up having 2 three-dimensional matrices and 1 two-dimensional one, described as follows:

```
// Matches schedule
// i -> players, j-> courts, k -> timeslots
// x[i][j][k] holds a value 0..1 where 0 means the player doesn't play in court_j in the timeslot_k, and 1 the opposite
IntVar[][][] x;

// Beginning of all matches
// i -> players, j-> courts, k -> timeslots
// g[i][j][k] holds a value 0..1 where 0 means the player doesn't play in court_j in the timeslot_k, and 1 the opposite
// Basically the same matrix as the previous one but it only holds the first timeslot of a match
IntVar[][][] g;

// Occupied courts
// i-> courts, j-> timeslots
// crt[i][j] holds a value 0..1 where 0 means the court_i is occupied in the timeslot_j, and 1 means the opposite
IntVar[][] crt;
```

With this approach the constraint that maps the schedule matrix to the game-starts matrix looks like this:

```
for (int p = 0; p < nPlayers; p++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < nCourts; c++) {
        for (int t = 0; t < nTimeslots - nTimeslotsPerMatch; t++) {
            if (nTimeslotsPerMatch == 1)
                solver.post(IntConstraintFactory.arithm(g[p][c][t], "=", x[p][c][t]));
            else
                solver.post(IntConstraintFactory.times(x[p][c][t], x[p][c][t + 1], g[p][c][t]));
        }               

        if (nTimeslotsPerMatch == 1)
            solver.post(IntConstraintFactory.arithm(g[p][c][nTimeslots - 1], "=", x[p][c][nTimeslots - 1]));
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < nTimeslotsPerMatch - 1; i++)
                solver.post(IntConstraintFactory.arithm(g[p][c][nTimeslots - i - 1], "=", 0));
    }
}
```

This uses the `times` constraint trick to map `x[p][c][t]` and `x[p][c][t + 1]` into `g[p][c][t]`.

However, that definition considers each match has a fixed duration of 2 timeslots. I want to change it so that duration is variable.

But if I want to have a variable match duration I would have to map more than two values in `x` to define the value in `g`. For example, if the match duration is 3 slots, to `map g[p][c][t]` I need to do `x[p][c][t] * x[p][c][t + 1] * x[p][c][t + 2]` but I can't do that with `times` or in a similar fashion it's being done right now.

So my questions is, as there is a constraint in Choco called `sum` where you can ensure the summation of a set of values is equal to a value, is there one to define the **product** of this set of values? If not, how can I do this?

Basically what I achieve to do is:

```
g[i][j][k] = x[i][j][k] + x[i][j][k + 1] * x[i][j][k + 2] * x[i][j][k + 3] * ... * x[i][j][nTimeslotsPerMatch - 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code comments, x is a set of binary variables (value is either 0 or 1), so you should declare it using BoolVar (which extends IntVar).

Multiplying binary variables gives 1 if all binaries are set to 1 or 0 otherwise. In other terms, you can use "LogicalConstraintFactory.and" or "IntConstraintFactory.minimum" constraints to get that multiplication. Look at IntConstraintFactory, you also have implication constraints that may be usefull.

Does it help?

Jean-Guillaume, 
https://www.cosling.com/

Comment: Can you tell me in a small sample code how to do what I am trying with using `and` and `minimum`? I just don't see how. Besides, the problem with BoolVars is that in another part of the problem I need these matrices to be IntVars because I need to calculate the number of courts in which each player plays and add a constraint to match that to the required number of matches each player must play. So how can I do both things? Anyway, I'd still like to know how to do a product.

Comment: To get a BoolVar bx equal to b1*b2*b3 :
solver.post(minimum(bx,new BoolVar[]{b1,b2,b3}));

Comment: if the domain is 0/1, it will be BoolVar objects whether you store them into an BoolVar matrix or an IntVar matrix, so I recommend the type of the matrix to be BoolVar[][]. As any BoolVar is an IntVar, you should not have problems. If so, please precise which instruction does not work.

Comment: Yes I totally understand it now. The way I see it multiplying boolean vars is the same than applying the AND opperation on them, so the same than using the `minimum` constraint. Now I need to apply an OR opperation over a set of vars, I guess using `maximum` would work in a similar fashion? Can you explain how using `LogicalConstraintFactory.and` and `or` would help my problem? As far as I can see the force to ensure that the constraint is applied over a set of variables, but I can't bond the "result" on a var the same way it's done with constraints like `sum`, `times`, `minimum` or `maximum`.

Comment: Even though this totally helped my particular problem that doesn't answer the main question: how do I define a product in Choco? Imagine I have a set of `IntVars` and I want to define a constraint over them that ensures that `x1 * x2 * x3 * ... * xn OP y`. Basically to achieve the same that `IntConstraintFactory.sum` does except that it should be a product instead of a sum.

Comment: About AND (and OR):
BoolVar result = LCF.and(b1,b2,...,bn).reif() will do the job. Reification consists of associating a constraint with a BoolVar that states whether the constraint is satisfied or not,i.e. result=1 <=> and(b1,b2,...bn)

Comment: About the n-ary product over IntVar, there is currently no implementation for that but you can use a chain of "times" constraints by introducing intermediary variables:
z = x1 * x2 * x3 can be reformulated as:
z = x1*x23 and x23 = x2*x3
etc. 
It is a bit boring but you can implement this reformulation into a static method once and for all. We may eventually add it to the library.